# Amount of possible distributions of 7 different coins among 3 different pockets.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So the exercise states the following: "There are 7 different coins and 3 different pockets. How many different ways to distribute those coins among the pockets do we have, considering that none of the pockets should be left empty"

I calculated all the cases possible $3^7=2187$ in the previous exercise.

So I calculated all the cases that don't suit me, which are the cases when at least one of the pockets is empty, which gave me $3*2^7=384$.

So in the end, the result is $2187-384=1803$. Is that a correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's indeed a correct solution.

Comment: Why did I ask the question in the first place was because a groupmate of mine says that we should be doing it differently. $2187$ (total cases) $-3$ (cases when 2 pockets are empty) $-(2^7-2\text{(cases when 2 pockets are empty)})$(cases when 1 pocket is empty). As a result she gets $1806$ and there comes confusion who is correct.

Comment: Your groupmate is counting things double. The number of cases when precisely one pocket is empty is not $3*2^7$: that number includes coin distributions where all coins are in the same pocket. There are three such distributions that she has to remove, whence the difference between you answer.